# Memory error after applying Agglomerative clustering on huge data

Tags: matlab

I have a csv file and I need to read just the values of column 2,4 and 5 and the data had 1048575 instances. I need to apply Agglomerative clustering on my data and when I run the code in Matlab it shows me the following error:

> requested 1*549754241025(4096GB) array exceeds maximum array size
> preference (503.7). This might cause Matlab to become unresponsive. I
> get this error with the above code

So I tried the following code using memory mapping approach to work with the data:

```
% Open the CSV file and read the header row
fid = fopen('data.csv', 'r');
header = {'Col2', 'Col4', 'Col5'};

% Read the data types from the second row of the file
formatSpec = '%*f %f %*f %f %f\n';

% Create a temporary file to store the binary data
tempFilename = [tempname, '.bin']; % Generate a unique filename
tempFid = fopen(tempFilename, 'w');

% Read and write the data to the temporary file in chunks
chunkSize = 10000;
while ~feof(fid)
    data = textscan(fid, formatSpec, chunkSize, 'Delimiter', ',');
    data = [data{1}, data{2}, data{3}];
    fwrite(tempFid, data', 'double');
end

% Close the file handles
fclose(fid);
fclose(tempFid);

% Create a memory-mapped file object for the binary data
m = memmapfile(tempFilename, 'Format', {'double', [length(header), Inf], 'data'});

% Perform agglomerative clustering using the memory-mapped data
tic;
Z = linkage(m.Data.data', 'average');
toc;

% Delete the temporary file
delete(tempFilename);
```

This code is running very slowly. Am I doing correctly? If not is there any faster approach to apply Agglomerative clustering on big data?